# Timeout when using AliasToBean with stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have some code that has a stored procedure execution to fill a DTO for use in displaying a table of data for a user.

The stored procedure will output, for example, 20 records with 17 columns, pulling from 9 tables, in roughly 1.3 seconds. The stored procedure works perfectly.

In my C# code, I have a DTO with all the same columns as the stored procedure, same data types. I run the following code to fill the DTO:

```
public IEnumerable<AgentActivityOrdersShortDTO> GetAgentActivityOrdersReport(DateTime currentDate, DateTime ordersBeforeDate, AgentActivityReportType reportType)
{
    var listOfOperations = _oms.GetSPSOperationsFromBalOperation((int)_ctx.TenantInfo.Operation, true).Select(o => o.SPSOperationMapping).ToList();
    var stringOfOperations = listOfOperations.Aggregate("", (current, o) => current + (o.ToString() + ","));

    IList<AgentActivityOrdersShortDTO> results = null;

    switch (reportType)
    {
        case AgentActivityReportType.ListingAgent:
             results = _sdsp.CurrentSession.CreateSQLQuery("exec GetActivityReport_OrderData_LA :CurrentDate, :OrdersBeforeDate, :OperationIds")
                       .SetParameter("CurrentDate", currentDate)
                       .SetParameter("OrdersBeforeDate", ordersBeforeDate)
                       .SetParameter("OperationIds", stringOfOperations)
                       .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(AgentActivityOrdersShortDTO)))
                       .List<AgentActivityOrdersShortDTO>()
                       .ToList();
             break;

        case AgentActivityReportType.SellingAgent:
             results = _sdsp.CurrentSession.CreateSQLQuery("exec GetActivityReport_OrderData_SB :CurrentDate, :OrdersBeforeDate, :OperationIds")
                    .SetParameter("CurrentDate", currentDate)
                    .SetParameter("OrdersBeforeDate", ordersBeforeDate)
                    .SetParameter("OperationIds", stringOfOperations)
                    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(AgentActivityOrdersShortDTO)))
                    .List<AgentActivityOrdersShortDTO>()
                    .ToList();
             break;
    }

    return results.ToList();
}
```

Some days, this runs with no issues. Other days, I get what I'm experiencing today:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

[image]

It seems to be intermittent, and I've occasionally "fixed" it by dropping and recreating the stored procedure, or by a flush&fill on the indexes of the database. But these aren't log-term solutions.

Thoughts or ideas on how to possibly fix would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If dropping and re-creating the stored procs "fixes" it, then it points to recompile of query plan solving the issue, and a less than optimal plan being cached.

To start with try adding "WITH RECOMPILE" to the 2 stored procs called by the code.

Check out parameter sniffing articles for background.
eg: **http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/**

Comment: The drop & recreate only fixes it *sometimes*. That's the problem I've seen.